# Change collection name in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Changing the name of a collection in mongodb can be achieved by copy the documents in the collection to a new one and delete the original.

But is there a simpler way to change the name of a collection in mongodb?

Comment: -1 for doing zero research - we call this laziness

Comment: hmm... why the downvote? This is an awesome question. +1. Yea I can google and this should show up.

Comment: +1 for putting this question into google search

Comment: I search google with 'how to change collection name mongo', and get this page :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
db.oldname.renameCollection("newname")
```

Answer (score 3):

Really? No google search?
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/renameCollection+Command

```
> db.oldname.renameCollection("newname")
```

Comment: hehe, careless Google search. Thanks.

Comment: This post is a lot easier to sift through.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.oldCollectionName.renameCollection("NewCollectionName")
```

Check [**Manual**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) here.